# error: cannot read property 'function' of undefined although it defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js

I just call a module property in different modules and it works well but when I call the same property in the following module it through an error says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

here is my js module

```
 'use strict';
    var createModule = require('./createModule');
    describe('my test module', function () {
        before(function (done) {
            createModule.create("Sample Data", function(test){
               done();
            });
        });

        it('function testing', function (done) {});
    });
```

the create function was tested in a different module and it works fine, but here it does not work. The used versions of my testing are:

- node v6.11.4
- mocha v3.5.3
- npm v3.10.10

What are the reasons for this issue?

Comment: dose createModule imported properly? By seeing your error I think createModule is undefined. Please check the import path.

Comment: @Atiq yes, it is imported properly, it is located at the same files where the code above is running. Also, as mentioned above the createModule.create was tested in different files and works.

Comment: I beg your pardon. But while you execute `createModule.create("Sample Data");` it seems `createModule` was undefined there. As the error says Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: That's right, that is how the compiler sees that is undefined while it is already defined

Comment: You can use assertion `console.assert(createModule  != undefined, "createModule  is Undefined")` before `describe()`

Comment: It threw an error which says createModule is Undefined.. weird about this problem !!

Comment: The only solution for this until now is the recreate the function inside this module instead of calling them which is a workaround solution !! that is overhead!

Comment: Another solution that I got is to define `var createModule = require('./createModule');` inside the `describe()` !!!

Comment: Please post the code from `createModule`. At least the export part. It would also be useful to know if `createModule` and your test file are in the same directory.